# Access wrapper app assets file to engine in rails3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rails-engines

I am creating a `rails engine` inside a `rails app`. I have a `test.js` file in `rails app` and I want to include this file in my `rails engine's` `application.js` file.
My engine is in `vendor/engines` folder.
How can I include wrapper(main) app's assets file into `engine`?

I am new for `rails engine`. If I miss something please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I am getting you right then you want some DRY code for using same `js` file in different places.

`Rails` starts looking from the `root` directory. So you just need to `require` the `js` file same as you did in `application.js`.

For example

```
//= require test
```